# Aplicación creada con Unity no inicia en Android

Tags: android, unity3d

Tengo un proyecto en Unity, he generado la apk y la he instalado en mi teléfono pero sale el siguiente mensaje:

```
Your device does not match the hardware requirements
```

He generado la apk varias veces, y en algunas ocasiones no aparece el mensaje pero la aplicación se cierra cuando la intento abrir.
Cuándo tenía una versión anterior del proyecto generé la apk y funcionaba sin problemas, en otro teléfono la aplicación funciona pero va muy lenta.

Comment: en este video puedes encontrar la solucion
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDoprc4m95s&t=23s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te puedo comentar que mi primera experiencia con Unity fue precisamente este problema, teniendo un dispositivo con "el último OS" que era en ese momento 5.0 (Samsung S6), obtenia el mensaje:

> Your device does not match the hardware requirements

Incluso encontré este thread que surgió desde el OS 2.1 de Android donde indican que dispositivos soportan las aplicaciones:

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/androids-that-work-with-unity-android.77388/page-7

Me parecía un poco raro que dispositivos nuevos no pudieran soportar las aplicaciones, encontré la razón, cuando se tienen definidas características de hardware necesarias para tu aplicación en el `AndroidManifest`, debes agregar la propiedad  `android:required="false"` esto para que en caso de no soportarlas al menos puedas ejecutar la aplicación, en algunos casos en realidad no son necesarias:

```
   <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false"/>
   <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false"/>
```